# Install GDAL on MacOS via Homebrew with Oracle support?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, oracle-dbms, mac, homebrew

I'm trying to install GDAL on a Mac so I can use `ogr2ogr` against an Oracle database. This was as easy as:

```
brew install gdal
```

However, it seems the Homebrew edition of GDAL doesn't ship with Oracle support. When I list install options with `brew options gdal`, I see flags for thigns like MySQL and Postgres but nothing for Oracle. Does anyone know how to build GDAL using Homebrew but include Oracle/OCI support?

Comment: Have you tried the method in my answer? I rarely use Macs so some feedback would be useful

Comment: Yes, thanks for sharing that. That seemed to be the right package but because of the nature of Oracle it requires you to place a zip file of the Instant Client in the Homebrew cache. I already had the IC installed and didn't want to muck with it, so I opted not to use this. But it may be helpful for others, so I'll mark it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [osgeo4mac](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/blob/master/README.md)?

```
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac 
brew install osgeo/osgeo4mac/gdal1-oracle
#or for GDAL 2x
brew install osgeo/osgeo4mac/gdal2-oracle
```

More info on taps is available in the [homebrew documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/brew-tap.md).

#### Note:

`osgeo4mac` is broken on Big Sur - [#1410](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/1410).

Comment: As of 2021-09-19 this no longer works. Or at least for Big Sur 11.5.2. Tapping osgeo causes a lot of errors and packages do not install.

Comment: @jebyrnes thanks, have added a link to the relevant issue