# Install GDAL on MacOS with Oracle (OCI driver) Support

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial

I am using MacOS Monterey. I am trying to install GDAL with oracle support. I have installed gdal using `brew install gdal` command but it doesn't include `OCI` driver. When I am trying to execute the folloing command

```
ogr2ogr -progress -lco SRID=3812 -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -nlt MULTIPOLYGON 
-nln a_municipalities -f "OCI" -overwrite OCI:daniel/daniel@<ip>/orcl "[DATAPATH]\Municipalities_A_AdMu.shp"
```

It is returning `ERROR 1: Unable to find driver` OCI'.`

I got a [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225340/install-gdal-on-macos-via-homebrew-with-oracle-support) here. But I think it is outdated. Now how to get gdal on MacOS Monterey with Oracle `OCI` driver?

Comment: If you're willing to build it youself, instead of using pre-built packages, there are some very detailed instructions at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434514/build-gdal-3-x-for-ios-and-macos .  However, it is focussed on iOS rather than macOS, and doesn't include Oracle driver, which you would have to add to the process yourself.  So this may not be what you're after.  Use a `PLATFORM` of `MAC` for macOS x86_64 or `MAC_ARM64` for macOS arm64 (or both).

Comment: Unfortunately no builds are available for macOS that include the Oracle plugins (OCI or GeoRaster). One option as suggested is do your own build - an uphill battle IMO. Or a simpler approach would be to take the Oracle-made build that is included within all 19c releases (`$ORACLE_HOME/md/gdal`) and package that as a docker image that you should be able to run on macOS. With the big caveat: this build is for X64 architecture: the docker container will run fine on X64 MacBooks, not so well on M1 (ARM64) MacBooks as it will involve emulation